# How to get the json array data and display in SPINNERS android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

How i can get the json data and display in spinners can u help me please
i want to display state name and code in spinners
Here is my Activity

below is the postman image in which i am getting state name and state code
so now how i can get and display in spinners
please help me

```
String country_id = "in";

    Call<ResponseBody> call = SignupClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .users(country_id);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Here is my Java Class

```
public class SignupClient {

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://74.207.233.160/";
private static SignupClient mInstance;
private Retrofit retrofit;

private SignupClient() {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static synchronized SignupClient getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null)
    {
        mInstance = new SignupClient();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public SignupApi getApi() {
    return retrofit.create(SignupApi.class);
}
}
```

Here is my Api

```
public interface SignupApi {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("find_states")
Call<ResponseBody> users(
        @Field("country_id") String country_id
);
}
```

Here is my postman image
[image: postman]

Comment: where is your pojo class?

Comment: y we need pojo class

Comment: Could you provide the response from your onResponse callback?

Comment: i am getting success response

Comment: but i am getting eror on "reponse.Body().string" ie null object reference

Comment: Check response code `response.code()`  first.

Comment: response.code() i am getting ok. with response code no problem but how i can read the data in postman and display in spinners

Comment: I think you need to change your response format because you are getting the array within array for a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (replace "FilterTable" with your Pojo class name)

```
class CustomArrayAdapterForSpinner(private val filterValues: List<FilterTable>) : BaseAdapter() {
private val inflater: LayoutInflater
var name: String? = null

val count: Int
    @Override
    get() = filterValues.size()

init {
    inflater = getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
}

@Override
fun getItem(position: Int): Object {
    return filterValues[position]
}

@Override
fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

@Override
fun getView(position: Int, view: View, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val holder: Holder
    var convertView = view
    if (convertView !=null) {
        holder = convertView.getTag()
    } else {
        holder = Holder()
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_filter, null)
        holder.chkTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkTxt)
        convertView.setTag(holder)
    }
    holder.chkTextView!!.setText(filterValues[position].getName())
    holder.chkTextView!!.setTag(if (filterValues[position].isSelection()) "unChecked" else "checked")
    return convertView
}

fun setSelection(str: String) {
    for (model in filterValues)
        model.setSelection(model.getName().equals(str))
}

internal inner class Holder {
    var chkTextView: CheckedTextView? = null
}
```

}

Comment: it means i want to create saperate class for this

Comment: Yes, this is the custom Adapter which you can use in Spinner

Comment: Also, you have the response data in the form of array of arrays, so, you won't be having a POJO class, but ````List<List<String>>````  (instead of ````List<FilterTable>````)